# Do I have to use BreezeController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, breeze

The [to-do list sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-require) is using a BreezeController to provide API's. `EFContextProvider` is used to provide `Metadata` string and methods like `SaveChanges()`.

The problem: it directly talks with the `DbContext`. I still want to have the flexibility to return my own view models instead of those domain models.

In a regular `ApiController`, we can return our own view models with ease. But if I turn to the regular `ApiController`, when calling the api, `breeze` asks for `Metadata`, which is supplied by

```
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata() {
    return _contextProvider.Metadata();
}
```

if we are using `BreezeController`.

So, my question is, do we have to use `BreezeController`? How do we return a customized view model using it? Or, if we use the regular `ApiController` for more flexibility, how could we provide the `Metadata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "BreezeController" is simply any API controller with the 'BreezeController' attribute.

"BreezeController" is simply a .NET attribute that helps .NET WebApi provide support for query filtering and ordering via OData "syntax" and well as json serialization support for entity graphs and type identity. Type identity is important so that breeze can track the entities within its entityManager and merge the results of queries and update relation properties.

The 'Metadata' method is only needed if you want to have the server provide metadata about the types that queries can return.  This same metadata can also be provided 'client side' so that you do not have to implement this method.  The NoDb sample in the breeze sample zip contains an example of this.

There is no breeze requirement that you return domain models instead of view models. Either works.  You simply have to provide the metadata for the types returned by whatever model you use.  Also take a look at the EntityQuery 'withParameters' method if you want to perform custom server side logic based on some arbitrary client side information.